# ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: “2”
services:
  web:
   build: .
   environment:
    MONGO_URI="mongodb://ravimongo:27017"
   ports:
    — “3000:3000”
   links:
    — ravimongo
   depends_on:
    — ravimongo
  ravimongo:
   image: mongo:3.2.6
   ports:
     — “27017:27017”
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version ("2.0", "2.1", "3.0") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

Version details are as follows:
docker-compose version

```
docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245
docker-py version: 2.1.0
CPython version: 2.7.12
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
```

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Fri Mar 24 00:00:50 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

I verified the yaml syntax in http://www.yamllint.com/ and https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator. I am unable to find the problem.

Comment: Similar: [Version in docker-compose is unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47972328/55075).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The YAML is valid. However, you are using a left double quotation mark `“` like so:

`version: “2”`

Based on the error, seems like Docker Compose is not able to parse the version correctly. If you use a [left double quotation mark](http://graphemica.com/%E2%80%9C) instead of a [quotation mark](http://graphemica.com/%22), the version which will be picked up by Docker compose will be `“2”` and not `2`, and hence it shall not be able to equate it to the supported versions (`"2.0"`, `"2.1"`, `"3.0"`). I would suggest changing it to the following:

`version: "2"`

Let me know if the errors still persist.

Answer (score 5):

Your editor is injecting smart-quotes instead of normal ascii quotes here:

```
version: “2”
```

This needs to be:

```
version: "2"
```

I'd recommend not writing yml files with that editor to avoid issues in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using vim. I am marking the other answer because it is a little more detailed for anybody who visits.

Comment: @ravikanth Vim did that? Did you have a plugin or keyboard for the different quote? I'm used to seeing that more from a word processor that a text editor.

Comment: yes. It is vim. I am not sure why it is happening in vim. I solved it using Sublime.

Comment: @ravikanth Sounds like someone may have installed this plugin: https://github.com/reedes/vim-textobj-quote/

Comment: I'm seeing vim-surround in there which has the ability to change quotes. May want to check that.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the error logs you should replace it by "2.0" instead of simply "2".

Answer (score 1):

Docker engine should be compliant with the file version. Following page can be checked which engine should be used with which compose file format.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

[image]