# Version in docker-compose is unsupported

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to install [this](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/tree/master/.examples/docker-compose/with-nginx-proxy/mariadb/apache) docker-compose configuration. As you can see, it has version 3.
When I run this with `docker-compose build --pull`, I got this error:

```
ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. 
You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. 
Either specify a version of "2" (or "2.0") and place your service definitions 
under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

If I remove version from .yml, then I get such error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for volumes: 'conf.d'
Unsupported config option for services: 'letsencrypt-companion'
Unsupported config option for networks: 'proxy-tier'
```

After reading documentation my first thoughts was about version incompatibility. So I've updated docker to `17.9.1-ce`.
And here is version of `docker-compose`:

```
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown
```

But errors are the same and I really have no idea about this.
Operation System: Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: As you might expect from the error, your version of `docker-compose` is outdated.  Upgraded to the current version of `docker-compose`.

Comment: @larsks if I am not idiot(I can be), I checked version of compose in github and current is 1.8.

Comment: @wuzzapcom Currently, the latest version is 1.18 (https://github.com/docker/compose/releases). Version 1.18 was released on December 19 2017, 1.8 was released on July 27 2017

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to upgrade docker compose and possibly the docker engine. Docker compose 3.0 files require docker engine version 1.13.0+ (and that version of compose). For more information see: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/, specifically the Compose and Docker Engine compatibility matrix.

Please note that version 1.18.0 comes after versions 1.8.0. It's version 1.18.0, not version 1.1.8.0. The minor version number just keeps increasing (e.g. 1.8.0 -> 1.9.0 -> 1.10.0 -> 1.11.0).

The latest version (when writing this) is 1.18, released on December 19 2017, 1.8 was released on July 27 2017 (https://github.com/docker/compose/releases). You are using an old version of docker that is not compatible with docker-compose 3 files.

Also, they changed the numbering of the docker enigines to reflect the release date: 17.9.0 is the September 2017 release (first number is the year, second number is the month).

Comment: But I've read documentation about installation. It said that I should remove Docker and docker-engine and install docker-ce instead, which I did. And in your link in compatability table, in first line: “3.4 -> 17.09.0+”. And I have this version. And 1.8 is the latest version for docker-compose, am I right? So what's wrong?

Comment: No, `1.18.0` is the latest version. Version `1.8.0` is about a year old and only supports up to version 2 of the format. I think you are mixing up `1.18.0` and `1.8.0`.

Comment: This answer explains how to upgrade to the latest docker-compose on debian-based systems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839028/how-to-upgrade-docker-compose-to-latest-version